# firebase firestore nested request

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested firebase structure as shown:

```
-users (collection)
      - user 1  (document)
            -Order (collection)
                 -Order1 (document)
                 -Order2 (document)
            -Personal Information (collection)

      - user 2  (document)
            -Order (collection)
                 -Order1 (document)
                 -Order2 (document)
            -Personal Information (collection)

...etc
```

How would I be able to list the name of all Users like [user1, user2, ...]

```
  const getOrders = async () => {
    await firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id);
        });
      });
  };
```

I have tried this set of code but does not work.

Comment: Don't store personal information in a separate collection. Store that data in the user document else you will need two reads for a single document when printing every users data at once. And if it is absolute necessary use same name for that document in the collection "Personal Information" which will make the code easier.

Comment: Or are you trying to print just the document ids in user collection?

Comment: "does not work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly didn't work? Do you get any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

I am more familiar with firebsase's RTDB but I managed to scrape this from their docs:

```
import { collection, query, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "users")

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Hope it works!

Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: Hello @HongHongChoy, does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question? Please also review the comments under the description.